# Collecting information about server usage and storaging in XML format using sysstat

Tags: debian, crontab, sysstat

I need to save the metrics below in XML format:

- Input / Output and transfer rate statistics (global, per device, per
  partition, per network filesystem and per Linux task / PID).

  CPU statistics (global, per CPU and per Linux task / PID)

  Memory, hugepages and swap space utilization statistics. Virtual
  memory, paging and fault statistics. Per-task (per-PID) memory and
  page fault statistics. Global CPU and page fault statistics for tasks
  and all their children.

The [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html) utility can monitor all metrics above.

```
sadf - Display data collected by sar in multiple formats and -x print the contents of the data file in XML format
```

I would like to save the metrics above every 2 minutes in XML format. How can I do it?